# Is it possible to get your router's external ip address without using a website?

Tags: unix, terminal, ip, ip-address, router

I was wondering if there was a way to find out your router's ip address without using a website like www.whatismyip.com.

I searched around, and I am beginning to think it is impossible. If that is the case, could someone explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Sometime the device will provide a web interface (common with small home devices like Cable Modems) where this kind of information can be found and/or configured.
- You may be able to make a command-line connection to the device using telnet or ssh, then use `/sbin/ifconfig` or the local equivalent.

Comment: Just wanted to add that in your routers web interface config page it'll usually be referred to as your ***WAN or Public IP Address***.

Comment: I will add that you can get more information with a "dig localhost". This seems to give me the ip address of my nameserver rather than what shows up on whatismyip.com.

Answer (score 2):

You want to know how are you being seen from outside, so to do this you need to use some  outside service.

Note, that it does not have to be just your router WAN address. If you are using http proxy for example the result can by an IP of host many hoops away from your router.

There are several sites with such service. Most is HTTP based, for convenience.

If you need to do it from terminal, you can:

```
wget -q -O - whatismyip.org
```

Comment: You don't really answer the original poster's question as you use a website to get the external IP address. Lots of those websites stop working when they consider that you make too much requests and some of them just "lie" as they use a lying DNS resolver (some countries force the major ISP to provide lying DNS resolvers to block some websites).

Answer (score 1):

in addition to dmckee's answer, you may even be able to query the device using snmp, although it usually needs some setting up and isnt particually user-friendly.

Answer (score 1):

Most routers support reading (and sometimes even writing) status information and further configuration options via uPnP. 
One of the information you can get via uPnP is the external IP address assigned to the router.

I don't know which uPnP clients are available for Linux but it may be worth a try...

Comment: Maybe GUPnP can help, I'm going to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

with some routers you can do a "get" on their admin interface somehow, and buried in the HTML will be the external IP address.

Comment: Do you have at least one example?